# Strange margin-top being inserted into code as an inline style. I can't find it

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to split my Bootstrap page into three parts - `header.php`, `(page).php`, `footer.php` and I am having trouble with an automatic insertion of a margin-top inline style on load. This isn't in my actual code and I can't find it in the style sheets.

The page looks perfectly fine prior to the split ( http://tinker.help/New_Site/index.html ).

When I split it into components `header_th.php` ; `index.php` ; `footer_th.php` ( http://tinker.help/New_Site/index_splitwrong.html ) the elements all come in and load, but I now have a large white space between the bottom of the `index.php` content and the beginning of `footer_th.php` content. If I look at the code in Web Developer tools, there is an inline style being set for the margin-top on the Footer element as follows: `footer id="footer" class="dark" style="margin-top: 509.2px;`

Clearly, this is coming from something calculated as no-one would set such an odd margin manually and it will disappear if I set the inline style to `footer id="footer" class="dark" style="display: inline;"` to disable any top or bottom margins (although it hoses all of the other formatting to do that.) I can't override this using `footer id="footer" class="dark" style="margin-top: 0px !important;"` in my code. Changing it in the Web developer tools fixes it but it is overridden by this automatically generated code and it doesn't stick if I update my code.

I assume I have messed up the divs somehow in the split, although I used the Web developer tools to make sure I was getting all of the code pieces cut from the consolidated index.html page and to ensure I didn't duplicate or miss and open or close div bits in the split pages.

Any advice? I am new to straight Bootstrap HTML5/CSS/PHP programming and have never tried to split the header and footer manually like this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to override that `margin-top`, you can add `!important` to your CSS value like this:

```
#footer{
  margin-top: 0px !important;
}
```

But make sure that you add this in your CSS style file or within a new `<style>` block in that page.

Regarding the automatic margin insertion, probably it's done by one of your Javascript code. Have a look at it!

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8y6vw1gr/

Comment: Thanks for the input. Can't seem to override the style anywhere - not in an in page style block or in the stylesheet itself. The .js is an interesting idea! I'll see what I can find. Or I might just build a page from scratch and repopulate it with content in case it's a div issue.

Comment: @MichelleTang I don't understand why you said it won't override. I have edited my answer and included a fiddle for you. So, if you remove the `!important` from the CSS in my fiddle, you would see that the inline `margin-top` is not overrided. But with the `!important`, it does override

Answer (score 0):

OK, I somehow messed up my splits. When I started from blank pages, it worked fine. It's also possible that I was loading my js libraries twice as the template loaded them in the head section and I was moving them to the end and may have duplicated them. Thanks all.